# Lookup default styles in wpf?

Tags: wpf, styles, default

In wpf, is it somehow possible to lookup the definition of the default style of a control?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739086/menuitem-style-through-controltemplate-in-resourcedictionary-not-applying-correc) I saw an example thereof, see: "just for a reference, here's the default MenuItem's style". Where did he/she find it?

Comment: You will usually find it if you search MSDN for `<control name> styles and templates`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832352/how-to-inspect-microsoft-windows-themes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How/Where to Find Microsoft Default Styles for WPF Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068830/how-where-to-find-microsoft-default-styles-for-wpf-controls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using Expressin Blend is the best answer for this. 
in Expression blend select the control on which you whould like to see the tamplate then right click and select the template then Edit a copy. this will create a copy os used tempalte will explorer the orignal template if you are not using any theme.

On the other hand you can look for http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/

Comment: Ok, I just noted that in visual studio designer 'template -> edit a copy' is also available.