# WPF: Where are the built-in styles defined

Tags: wpf

I have a RepeatButton in a Toolbar. I want it to have the same visual appearance as the ToolBar-Buttons. But ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey doesn't work because of the different TargetType. So where are the built-in styles defined (for various Themes) and how can I clone the ToolBar.ButtonStyle for RepeatButton?

Comment: I can't help you with the 1st part of the question (Where are the default styles defined? In some theme(s), which again are stored in some DLL file, somewhere, i guess...). But to get the (default) control template for a control in XAML form, you might follow the advice given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548268/2819245.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lookup default styles in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050771/lookup-default-styles-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are defined in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationFramework*` assemblies. You could use a decompiler such as [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to extract the templates, or you can right-click on a control in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose `Edit Template`->`Edit a Copy` to copy the default template into your XAML markup.

> I tried this and I got the `Template` for `ToolBar`, but not the style for ToolBarButton. The search ends at ToolBarButtonStyleKey, but can't find ToolBarButtonStyle for WPF.

It's right there:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ƻ}" Property="Border.BorderBrush"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ƺ}" Property="Border.Background"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ƻ}" Property="Border.BorderBrush"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ƺ}" Property="Border.Background"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ƾ}" Property="Border.BorderBrush"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ƽ}" Property="Border.Background"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Property="Control.Foreground"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8, I tried this and I got the Template for ToolBar, but not the style for ToolBarButton. The search ends at ToolBarButtonStyleKey, but can't find ToolBarButtonStyle for WPF.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to get more into dotPeek.